# how to put a link_to internal resource in a model with rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a requirement to include internal links in a DataTables report.  Therefore I must return the report data from Model#as_json, e.g.:

```
class Error < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper # provides link_to
  include ActionController::UrlWriter # provides *_path

  def as_json(options={})
  {
    :date => self.created_at,
    :level => self.level,
    :ip => self.ip,
    :title => truncate(self.title, :length => 100),
    :show => link_to('Show', error_path(self)),
    :hide => self.handled ? "" : "#{link_to 'Hide', handle_error_path(self)}"
  }
end

...
```

What an effort figuring out what I needed to include. But now I get error: "can't convert String into Hash"

This is because 'link_to' uses 'url_for' which is a method that both UrlHelper and UrlWriter both have which actually behave differently.

So I'm at my wits end. If someone can help me figure out how to do this, or show me how to fulfill the requirements without breaking MVC I will be very grateful either way.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the link manually:

```
:hide => self.handled ? "" : "<a href='/handle_error?params=something'>Hide</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I will follow up my own question with what turned out to be the best solution: use the json_builder gem and keep your json in the view where it belongs :)